# Will a transformer with no output overheat

Tags: transformer

I have replaced my old doorbell with a wifi model.  Because of renovations to my home over time I cannot access the transformer of the old doorbell to disconnect it.  If I just remove the old doorbell and push button, will the transformer overheat with no output load?

Comment: think about this ... doorbell transformers have the output connected only when someone presses the button at the door ... the rest of the time the output is disconnected .... facepalm time ... lol

Comment: It won't overheat, but having equipment connected to the mains without the possibility to disconnect it is the real issue, here.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is the assumption that it is in good condition and not subject to invasion of moisture. Self-heating helps with this issue. A doorbell transformer with no load stays at a idle current state, consuming only a few watts off of a 120 VAC or 220 VAC line. This will keep it warm to the touch, but if you have icy-cold winters the metal case will become cool or cold to touch.

The only risk with a transformer with no access to disable is a sharp rise in line voltage due to lightning or a cut neutral wire, or pinched output wires. It would behoove you to find what circuit breaker disables this transformer and mark it, just in case.